# Unity3D Transparent material with alpha set to 1 has see through parts

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working with HDRP and shader graphs and I am having an issue where some materials which are set to transparent with the alpha set to 1 has some parts that are showing through. It looks like the material showing through is the same material, just on a different part of the building.

Items showing through material

[image]

Here's the base material setup:

[image: material setup]

I'm using a transparent material because I need to lower the alpha when the player is behind the building.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information or screen shots are needed.